# LINQ query to get multiple values

Tags: .net, xml, linq

I am desperately trying to find a good resource on LINQ, but found nothing that explains what I am trying to do.

I have an xml file and part of the structure looks like such:

```
    <Schedule>
       <%= New XAttribute("Own", own) %>
       <%= New XAttribute("Sched", sched) %>
       <%= New XAttribute("Sub", sub) %>
    </Schedule>
```

So, I am trying to understand with LINQ, how to create a distinct list of the combined values? At the moment I am just grabbing all elements called Schedule like so `Dim scheds = xmlProj.Root...<Schedule>`, but I really want to know how I can just do it without having to iterate each entry then and do it manually.

At this stage I have hit a blank but I know some of the format:

```
Dim scheds = (From a in xmlProj.Root...<Schedule>.Elements
              Where (?) select ?).Distinct.ToList
```

How do I combine the string value of all 3 attributes into one value that I can use? Please, not the String.Join(x, ", "), that I know. How do I do it inside the LINQ query? While I suspect it has something to do with a Join, it also occurs to me that somewhere deep in my past I have seen a statement where inside an SQL query they created a variable that contained the values. I just can't for the life of me figure it out.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was :

```
Dim schedstest = (From a In xmlProj.Root...<Schedule>
                          Select name = String.Join(" ",
                                        a.Attribute("Own").Value,
                                        a.Attribute("Sched").Value,
                                        a.Attribute("Sub").Value)).Distinct.ToList
```

So I was half wrong, but at least I was half right! And I learnt something. What a day. Hope this helps someone else out there. And in case you are interested I can change case, and manipulate the strings once I had them.